# AIR Run the same app twice for testing

Tags: air

I am working on a multiplayer application and I need to run for testing the same application twice (so one can create a game and other can join). Is there any feasible solution to achieve this without:

- Creating a .exe out of the project;
- Using two computers

Ideally I should be able to keep one of the instances constantly opened while the other can be easily recompiled for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different application id's. Under Windows, I can change swf file of installed application and run it, it doesn't complains, so you may overwrite app with newer version without reinstall.

Comment: I have managed to use your hint in a different way. I started an app, unlinked it from debugger, changed ID in *-app.xml hit F11... And Voila, two instances of the same app are running concurrently :)